# Wrong output in calculating average program

Tags: c

For years, I don't do anything in C and now I can't do simple things, I was accustomed to `cin` and `cout` and now Java. I was trying to make a simple program to calculate the average X amount of exams notes. The output are "random numbers" and checking to interrupt the program occurs before entering a note. Why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int numeroDeNotas;
    float nota = 0.0;
    float notaAuxiliar = 0.0;
    char continuar;
    int media;

    do{
    printf("Enter the exam grade\n");
    scanf("%f", &notaAuxiliar);
    nota += (int) notaAuxiliar;
    numeroDeNotas++;
    printf("Do you want to continue? Enter n if you want to stop\n");
    scanf("%c", &continuar);
    }while(continuar != 'n');

    printf("%d\n\n", nota);
    printf("%d\n\n", numeroDeNotas);

    media = nota/numeroDeNotas;
    printf("Average grade: %d", media);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 0) newline  when input `notaAuxiliar` into `continuar`, So `scanf("%c", &continuar);` change to `scanf(" %c", &continuar);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nota` is a `float`, but you are using `%d` format code to print it. `%d` expects an `int`; you need `%f` to print floating point numbers.

C's standard I/O formatting is definitely not typesafe. When you provide a format code, you have to make sure the corresponding argument has the right type. However, if you had compiled with the `-Wall` option (at least, with `gcc` or `clang`), the compiler would have warned you.

Also, `scanf("%c", &continuar);` reads a single character without skipping whitespace, which will be the character immediately following the number read by `scanf("%f", &notaAuxiliar);`. That character is most likely a newline. You need to skip whitespace before reading the `y` or `n`, so you could use:

```
scanf(" %c", &continuar);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numeroDeNotas
```

variable is declared but no where initialized. and you are incrementing in `do while` loop.

```
media = nota/numeroDeNotas;
printf("Average grade: %d", media);
```

and you are using garbage value to calculate `media` which is undefined output. initialize numeroDeNotas to zero.

Answer (score 0):

numeroDeNotas was declared with a variable type - float. So you can't use %d later in your code when writing a printf statement.